# CSS media query rules not being applied

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm tasked with making a small update to an existing widget on a dashboard-style website.  The current widget looks great on larger screens but terrible on smaller devices.  I'm trying to add a few CSS rules that should only be applied when the width of the display is at or below 768px.

I have worked with responsive design a bit using Bootstrap.  I haven't had to roll-my-own @media queries.

Here is the CSS...

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {  // Bootstrap sm.
    #sidenav { position: static; text-align: center; }
    #sidenav .primary-systems li {
        display: inline-block;
        width: auto;
    }
}
/* Stuff I added above;  stuff I inherited below */
#sidenav { width:265px; background-color: #fff; position: relative; left: -44px; top: 16px; border: 1px solid #000; padding: 8px 0; }
#sidenav ul { margin: 0; padding-left: 0; }
#sidenav div.hr { border-bottom: 1px dotted #353535; margin: 0 auto 15px auto; }
#sidenav li { list-style-image: none; list-style-type: none; margin-left: 0; }
#sidenav li a { white-space: nowrap; display: block; width: 170px; height: 50px; padding-left: 80px; font-family: 'lato'; font-weight: 400; line-height: 50px; font-size: 18px; color: #353535; text-decoration: none; background: transparent url("/jasig-widget-portlets/images/icons/sidenav.png") no-repeat 15px 0; }
#sidenav li a:hover { background-color: #f3f3f3; }
#sidenav .angel a { font-family:'Lato', sans-serif; background-position: 15px 0; }
#sidenav .web-advisor a { font-family:'Lato',sans-serif; background-position: 15px -50px; }
#sidenav .tartan-card a {font-family:'Lato',sans-serif; background-position: 15px -100px; }
#sidenav .course-schedule a {font-family:'Lato',sans-serif; background-position: 15px -150px; }
#sidenav .directory a {font-family:'Lato',sans-serif; background-position: 15px -200px; }
#sidenav .faq a {font-family:'Lato',sans-serif; background-position: 15px -250px; }
#sidenav .help-desk a {font-family:'Lato',sans-serif; background-position: 15px -300px; }
#sidenav .financial-aid a {font-family:'Lato',sans-serif; background-position: 15px -350px; }
#sidenav .transcripts a {font-family:'Lato',sans-serif; background-position: 15px -400px; }
#sidenav .important-dates a {font-family:'Lato',sans-serif; background-position: 15px -450px; }
#sidenav .semesters a {font-family:'Lato',sans-serif; display: none; }
#sidenav .banner { margin: 15px auto 15px 30px; }
#sidenav .support {font-family:'Lato',sans-serif; margin-top: 15px; padding-left: 20px; }
#sidenav p.secure {font-family:'Lato',sans-serif; margin: 20px; }
#sidenav p.server { margin-left: 24px; }
```

The chrome dev tools show the current version of this file in the Sources tab (not a cache problem).  The inherited CSS rules are working;  the lines I added have not effect.  They don't even show up in the list of overridden rules when you look at the elements in Chrome dev tools.

Can anyone see what I'm missing?

Comment: unrelated to your problem, your selectors are unnecessarily specific, and will be difficult to maintain.

Comment: @zzzzBov -- Nice insight, but I fear not in this case.  This is a dashboard-style website full of small page elements (widgets) that are developed, maintained, and styled independently.  I'm showing only 1 of about 10 CSS files loaded by the complete DOM.  We use selectors with greater specificity to avoid impacting each other's areas.

Comment: There are much better ways of managing styles than increasing specificity. Consider using a preprocessor  like LESS or Sass and taking advantage of a scalable technique such as SMACSS, OOCSS, or BEM.

Comment: We use LESS commonly and love it, though this file doesn't.  I've come across SMACSS before, but I'm having trouble recognizing how it will help us (not saying it won't) by reading the home page.

Comment: Think of it this way, if you separate each module/widget/block/object/whatever-you-want-to-call-it into a separate file, you can give the name of the file the same name as the module. If you're making the `.sidenav` module, the `sidenav.less` file is where those styles go. Anyone who authors new code would have to create a new file, which would prevent them from running into a naming conflict. You can then make smaller and smaller reusable modules knowing that it won't conflict so long as everyone adheres to the standards.

Comment: That sounds very organized, but I'm missing something.  Is there something about SMACSS or OOCSS that scopes the stylistic rules within a less file to a region on the page based on the filename?  (E.g. 'sidenav.less' defines rules that apply only to the '#sidenav' element and descendants).  That kind of thing could be pretty helpful if it's engine-enforced;  if it's a matter of convention, it's less helpful (but perhaps helpful nevertheless).  FWIW the sidenav widget is in a different compilation unit -- different .war -- from 97% of the other elements on the page.

Comment: I use BEM specifically, so this reply is biased toward that implementation: all classes used end up prefixed with the appropriate block. `.sidenav` would have a `.sidenav__title` and a `.sidenav__list`, or when descendant selectors are used, `.sidenav a` would style only links within sidenav. Those methodologies help make sure there's no overlap between modules so long as you follow convention. I haven't seen (m)any good tools for enforcing these conventions. If you're working with developers who can't be bothered to follow a convention, what makes you think your current styles will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your media query below the inherited rules. The CSS parser will apply any rules that apply as it parses the document in order. You need your overrides to be parsed after the base rules.

**Update:** As a side note, CSS doesn't support `//` comments, so the parser may be getting confused by `// Bootstrap sn.`. At least your `text-align` and `.primary-systems` rules should be applied even with the current ordering.

Comment: Didn't start working until I followed the advice in your Side Note.

Answer (score 1):

Your selectors are being overridden by other selectors with the same specificity that occur after the selectors in the media query.

[You can learn more about how the cascade works in css in the w3c docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascade).

The quick solution is to move your media queries below your other selectors.